# Caching the mean of a Vector in R (list)

Tags: r, caching, mean

This is a follow up to [Caching the mean of a Vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904683/caching-the-mean-of-a-vector-in-r) and is specifically about the last line of code

```
list(set = set, get = get, setmean = setmean, getmean = getmean)
```

I am not understanding what the `list` is doing.  The answer given at the linked question:

> list() returns the 'special vector' containing all of the functions just defined

does not make much sense to me. I think that `makeVector` should be returning an object which has the approriate `set` and `get` methods, but now sure how this `list()` is doing that.  What is the `set` on the left-hand side and what is the `set` on the right-hand side?

```
 makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
         m <- NULL
         set <- function(y) {
                x <<- y
                m <<- NULL
        }
        get <- function() x
        setmean <- function(mean) m <<- mean
        getmean <- function() m
        list(set = set, get = get,
             setmean = setmean,
             getmean = getmean)
 }
```

Comment: Do you know what a `list` is in R? It is a "basic" type in R and basically is a vector whose elements are arbitrary R objects (consider that also functions are objects in R). Elements of a list can be named through the `tag=value` paradigm. `list(set=set)` means: create a list whose first element is named `set` and has the value of the `set` object (which has been defined before).

Comment: @nicola: I am just starting on `R` so obviously am not clear on this. So the left-hand `set` is the name of that can be used to access the `set` function on the right-hand side. Thus, if the the code was `setValue <- function(y)`, the `list` parmater would be `set = setValue`. So the "method" to initialize the data would still be `set` and that would call the function `setValue`. Is that correct?  That is, `setValue` is not available to be invoked directly?

Comment: You should probably work through An Introduction to R. Closures and function factories seem to be too advanced for your current level of understanding.

Comment: @Roland: Well, yeah I know that this is advanced for me -- that is why I am struglling. Do you have any insight regarding my comment above? If my understanding is correct, wouldn't different names (when this example is given in a course) have made it clearer?

Comment: There is nothing confusing here if you understand scoping. If you don't understand scoping you can't understand this example at all.

Comment: @Roland: Do you have a link that will help me understand the scoping you are referring to.

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping

Answer (score 1):

```
> z<- makeVector()
> z
```

### the above statement will return a list of all the four functions in "makeVector " function,i.e., $set, $get, $setmean, $getmean

```
$set
function (y) 
{
    x <<- y
    m <<- NULL
}
<environment: 0x0000000008935dc8>

$get
function () 
x
<environment: 0x0000000008935dc8>

$setmean
function (mean) 
m <<- mean
<environment: 0x0000000008935dc8>

$getmean
function () 
m
<environment: 0x0000000008935dc8>
```

### now you can access each function as a list object as shown below:

```
> z$set(c(1:20))
> z$get()
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> z$setmean(mean(z$get()))
> z$getmean()
[1] 10.5
```

### I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I provide an extensive walkthrough of the two functions in the second Johns Hopkins *R Programming* Assignment in my article [Demystifying makeVector()](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-breakingDownMakeVector.md).

That said, here is the answer to how the `list()` statement works in `makeVector()`.

#### Step 3: Create a new object by returning a list()

Here is the other part of the "magic" in the operations of the `makeVector()` function. The last section of code assigns each of these functions as an element within a `list()`, and returns it to the parent environment.

```
list(set = set, get = get,
     setmean = setmean,
     getmean = getmean)
```

When the function ends, it returns a fully formed object of type `makeVector()` to be used by downstream R code. One other important subtlety about this code is that each element in the list is [named](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list/named-list-members). That is, each element in the list is created with a `elementName = value` syntax, as follows:

```
    list(set = set,          # gives the name 'set' to the set() function defined above
         get = get,          # gives the name 'get' to the get() function defined above
         setmean = setmean,  # gives the name 'setmean' to the setmean() function defined above
         getmean = getmean)  # gives the name 'getmean' to the getmean() function defined above
```

Naming the list elements is what allows us to use the `$` [form of the extract operator](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md) to access the functions by name rather than using the `[[` form of the extract operator, as in `myVector[[2]]()`, to get the contents of the vector.

Here it's important to note that the `cachemean()` function REQUIRES an input argument of type `makeVector()`. If one passes a regular vector to the function, as in

```
 aResult <- cachemean(1:15)
```

the function call will fail with an error explaining that `cachemean()` was unable to access `$getmean()` on the input argument because `$` does not work with atomic vectors. This is accurate, because a primitive vector is not a list, nor does it contain a `$getmean()` function, as illustrated below.

```
> aVector <- 1:10
> cachemean(aVector)
Error in x$getmean : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```